# Shell script: how to read only a portion of text from a variable

Tags: shell, ash

I'm developing a little script using ash shell (not bash).

Now i have a variable with the following composition:

```
VARIABLE = "number string status"
```

where number could be any number (actually between 1 and 18 but in the future that number could be higher) the string is a name and status is or on or off
The name usually is only lowercase letter.

Now my problem is to read only the string content in the variable, removing the number and the status.

How i can obtain that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways; one is to leverage `$IFS` and use a while loop - this will work for a single line quite happily - as:

```
echo "Part1 Part2 Part3" | while read a b c
do
    echo $a
done
```

alternatively, use `cut` as follows:

```
a=`echo $var | cut -d' ' -f2`
echo $a
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `cut`?

```
name=$(echo "$variable" | cut -d " " -f 2)
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently, Ash doesn't understand `$(...)`.  Hopefully you can do this instead:

```
name=`echo "$variable" | cut -d " " -f 2`
```

Comment: $(...) isn't known to ash. they need to use backticks instead.

Comment: Are you sure @ChrisJ? I checked on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_shells#Inter-process_communication) and it does state that `ash` supports `command substitution`.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this last night and `$(...)` threw an error, whilst backticks didn't. It's working this morning. Damned if I know what's going on. {confused}

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
name=$(echo "$variable" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
myvar="word1 word2 word3 wordX"
set -- $myvar

echo ${15}    # outputs word 15
```